# Remove pattern from a line in file with Grep/sed/awk combo, pattern is another column

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have two columns (or could separate as two files) in a huge file and i need to remove the duplicate city name in the state/area column.

```
los angeles      los angeles ca, usa, west
new york         new york ny, usa, east
vancouver        vancouver bc can, west
...
```

can i somehow pipe column one as a variable and pattern match and remove from column 2?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? (this should be quite easy if you're familiar with regex). Apparently the columns are tabs/spaces separated, right ?

Comment: is it quite easy? how do you know what to pattern match on?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You use something called "backreference"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `awk`, with input file

```
los angeles     los angeles ca, usa, west
new york        new york ny, usa, east
vancouver       vancouver bc can, west
paris   france paris, europe
berlin  germany berlin
mardrid ola, spain
```

where columns are tab separated properly.

```
awk -F\\t '{if (i=index($2,$1)) $2=substr($2,0,i-1) substr($2,i+length($1)) ; print }' u
```

where

- `-F\\t` use tab as deleimiter
- `i=index($2,$1)` search occurence of $1 in $2
- `if ( )` if found ..
- `$2=substr($2,0,i-1) substr($2,i+length($1))` replace $2 by substring where $1 is stripped (this assume only one occurence of $1)
- `print` print result

result

```
los angeles  ca, usa, west
new york  ny, usa, east
vancouver  bc can, west
paris france , europe
berlin germany
mardrid ola, spain
```

Comment: beware of resritictive condition, if lines are extraced from excel (.tsv), that should be OK, but if not ...